# Angular2 Memory Leaks - Dom Nodes

Tags: angular, memory-leaks

As show in the picture, the Nodes keep increasing. I have a lot of ngFor loops, that I currently am not using the async pipe on - would this be the root cause?

ngOnDestroy are firing when switching.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, any lifecycle hook will cause the observable tree to recalculate. Are you using parameters for your route by chance? onDestroy is specifically used when you leave that component entirely, not rerender data. If you are using components inline, then every single time that component rerenders you will be calling its OnDestroy hook. If you can provide code, maybe I can assist you further unless that helps spark something.

Comment: I would, but I was switching between multiple components, shouldn't that remove everything once it has left? On some of them I did have params I was subscribing to, but I did unsubscribe from them. I also have  a couple directives receiving information, on one of them, from one 'main' component that receives the data. Do I need to do something with the @input on leaving?

Comment: Barely missed 5 minutes - those directives implement OnChanges

Comment: Angular 2 does a good job handling the native observables, the only reason that you would have a subscription to an observable is one that youre managing yourself. If you have an observable, you must unsubscribe from it prior or during the destruction. If youre parent component contains an inline component, that will be triggered every component route change as well.

Comment: Yes, they would. Are you using the onChanges to handle ur inputs? If they are in the directive scope then you should set a ChangeDetectionStrategy and handle the changes explicitly with the ChangeDetectorRef. Are you familiar?

Comment: If you cant narrow down the source of your leak, changing the change detection strategy in each component until your leak ceases will help u narrow down the source as well. I prefer more control over my observables and less computing power by managing them myself.

Comment: Yeah, I was using it to handle them. I had not heard of them. I checked out a few plunkers, and I'm definitely gonna be implementing them. Thanks man for diving into this for me, I really appreciate it. I'm definitely gonna dive deep into the api docks, I'm probably missing some gems in there